# git push produces unknown error about Agent process id on remote server

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am trying to push from local to remote git repository on a ubuntu server using

```
git push production master
```

I keep getting this error message

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Agen

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So i did

```
ssh <hostname> git-receive-pack <path-to-git-repo>
```

And it gave me this error

```
Agent pid 17671
008c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{} report-status 
delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta agent=git/2.7.4
0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical of an ssh connection which prints something in stdout.
For instance, the remote account used on the Ubuntu server has a `.basrch` or a `.profile` which has echo in them.

Make sure an `ssh -T <account>@<ubuntu.server>` does not print anything.

For instance, if that account would itself setup an ssh agent (as in "[Why eval the output of ssh-agent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351727/7490)"), that would print the ssh agent pid.

Try and avoid that, especially considering the ssh agent is more for the client side (i order to cache ssh private key passphrases)

Comment: This time excessive text is `Agent pid 17671`. Seems like a debugging output from some "agent". I also see "agent=git/2.7.4".

Comment: @phd Agreed. The server side seems to display something

Comment: thanks. but i cant find where the server is displaying a message, i have checked the two files you suggested and found just one line of echo and commented it out

Comment: @JoshuaMajebi check if those files are doing an eval ssh-agent: see http://rabexc.org/posts/pitfalls-of-ssh-agents

Comment: the above command prints out  -- Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1020-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

46 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


*** System restart required ***
Agent pid 19721

Comment: @JoshuaMajebi Can you try and comment that (on the server side), to see if the same error message persists on the client side?

Comment: @ Vonc...thanks that made the error go away and the push successful

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that i had setup an ssh agent in my .bashrc file while trying to setup another repository from github and do a git clone. But like VonC pointed out that agent was printing out the message above and blocking me from pushing to the new repo.